# Run program as administrator in domain user without writing password for admin account

Tags: windows-10, administrator, uac

I have some computers on a domain, where users login in with their account (eg. domain\paul.spotka).

Sometimes I must do something on some computers remotely. I try to use AnyDesk and Aeroadmin for those things, but when I must write my admin account credentials, I don't see a window to write it into (UAC windows) on my AnyDesk or other software remote connection. Only the user sees it on their screen. I get only a stuck and frozen desktop.

Is it possible to do something with that? When I open AnyDesk as an administrator and paste my admin credentials and then I connect from other computer everything is OK, so is there some method to open the program from a shortcut, parameters with domain administrator credentials in such a way that the user does not know the admin password? (In other words, I must give them to him, and it makes no sense for security reason)

Comment: Perhaps try different remote access software. We make a VPN connection to remote machines and then use Windows Remote Desktop Connection to log into the remote machine as administrator and all works. Maybe try TeamViewer instead as it is more fully featured.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. As for why you connect but don't see the UAC prompt, that's because the AnyDesk software is running without admin credentials and cannot "see" the UAC prompt because it's displayed on the Secure Desktop, which is only accessible to code running with admin permissions.

Comment: So your remote control software doesn't support viewing the Windows Security screen. You should find a product that does.

Comment: You will need to install AnyDesk as a service on the remote computer. That way it can give itself administrative access.